# Laravel: Delete data with wrong ID

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I use the Delete button to delete data, but when deleting data, the deleted data does not match the rows I mean, but the data that is deleted is the data that is at the top of the table

when I use `return $meja`, it should appear id 7 but id 1 instead

For further details :

view :

```
@foreach($data as $row)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{$no++}}</th>
        <td>{{$row->no_meja}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->keterangan}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{route('meja.edit',['meja'=>$row->id_meja])}}" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a href="#" data-id="" class="btn btn-danger confirm_script mr-3">
                <form action="{{ route('meja.destroy',['meja'=>$row->id_meja])}}" id="delete" method="POST">
                    @method('DELETE')
                    @csrf
                </form>
                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

here is my javascript

```
<script>
    $(".confirm_script").click(function(e) {
        // id = e.target.dataset.id;
        swal({
            title: 'Yakin hapus data?',
            text: 'Data yang dihapus tidak bisa dibalikin',
            icon: 'warning',
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                $('#delete').submit();
            } else {
                swal('Your imaginary file is safe!');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my controller :

```
public function destroy(Meja $meja)
{
    $meja->delete();
    return redirect()->route('meja.index')->with('destroy',' Berhasil dihapus!');
}
```

Here is my Router :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
    Route::view('/','admin/dashboard.index');
    //---MASAKAN---//
    Route::resource('masakan','MasakanController');
 Route::post('admin/masakan/updatestatus/{masakan}','MasakanController@UpdateStatus')->name('masakan.updateStatus');
    //---MEJA---///
    Route::resource('meja','MejaController');
    //---ADMIN-ACCOUNT---/
    Route::resource('adminaccount','AdminController');   
});
```

Comment: If you are using resources type route on meja then why are you sending id instead you should send the object of meja.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is the proper ID submitted to your controller?

Comment: One recommendation as a senior dev, please DO NOT write code in other language than ENGLISH, you have a mix of English and Indonesian (if google is correct), why would you write in both languages ? At least stick to one !

Comment: @NicoHaase yap i tried to return the id like this `return $meja`

Comment: `return $meja`  would return an object, not an ID - but what does that yield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because of id confliction. your every form id is `delete` but in a dom there should be a single element with an id. when you are using sweet alert to submit the delete form, the very first form with `delete` id got submitted, hence the first item got deleted. use unique id or class instead. an example for you using class

form

```
<form action="{{ route('meja.destroy',['meja'=>$row->id_meja])}}" class="delete_form" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
</form>
```

sweet alert code

```
$('.delete_form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            event.currentTarget.submit();
        }
    })
});
```